# Plot a product of Beta distributions

Tags: plotting, distributions

I would like to plot the PDF of the product of a $Beta(1,1)$ and $Beta(3/2,1/2)$ random variables. I can use the following to calculate the PDF at a point $x$:

```
PDF[TransformedDistribution[u v, {u \[Distributed] BetaDistribution[1, 1], 
v \[Distributed] BetaDistribution[3/2, 1/2]}], x]
```

However, to work out the PDF at a point (take $x=0.5$ for example), the above takes about 10 minutes on my computer.

I could leave my computer overnight, and it should be able to plot the above PDF using $Plot$, however, I was wondering whether there are any quicker alternatives?

Note: I want to plot the distribution's PDF exactly, *not* an approximation by drawing randomly first a $Beta(1,1)$ then multiplying it by a draw from $Beta(3/2,1/2)$, then looking at a histogram.

Best,

Ben

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I can tell you are recalculating the transformed distribution too often in your plot. Calculate and store the resulting PDF once and then use it for your plots.

```
tpdf = PDF[
  TransformedDistribution[
   u v, {u \[Distributed] BetaDistribution[1, 1], 
    v \[Distributed] BetaDistribution[3/2, 1/2]}], x]
```

Once you have `tpdf` your plot will return immediately since you are not recalculating it for each value of `x`.

```
Plot[tpdf, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: …and if OP would rather skip the use of an auxiliary variable, there's the option setting `Evaluated -> True`.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Is this an option on `Plot`?  I can't seem to find it in 10.2

Comment: @Edmund - use `Plot[Evaluate[PDF[..., x]], {x, 0, 1}]`

Comment: Yes, it's an option for `Plot[]`.